# Como resolver erro C# "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."?

Tags: c#, foreach, nullpointerexception, objetos

Estou tentando finalizar um projeto só que está apresentando erro da parte do foreach, sendo que no VSCODE não informa nenhum problema. Estou aprendendo C# agora e não estou conseguindo resolver sozinha.

esse é homecontroller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Projeto_PetVet.Models;

namespace Projeto_PetVet.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Servicos()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public IActionResult PreAgendamento()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PreAgendamento(DadosConsulta consulta)
    {
        Consulta.addDados(consulta);
        return View("olhaDados");
    }

    public IActionResult Sucesso()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult olhaDados() {
    List<DadosConsulta> consulta = Consulta.olhaDados();
    return View(consulta);
    }


    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
}
```

Esses são meus Models: Consulta.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Projeto_PetVet.Models
{
public class Consulta
{
    static List<DadosConsulta> infos = new List<DadosConsulta>();

    public static void addDados(DadosConsulta consulta) {
        infos.Add(consulta);
    }

    public static List<DadosConsulta> olhaDados() {
        return infos;
    }
}
}
```

DadosConsulta.cs

```
namespace Projeto_PetVet.Models
{
public class DadosConsulta
{
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string Animal {get; set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}
    public string Telefone {get; set;}
    public string Horario {get; set;}
    public string Necessidade {get; set;}
}
}
```

E essa é a minha View, onde o erro está aparecendo no foreach:

```
@model List<DadosConsulta>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Pré agendamento";
}
<h1>Confirme suas informações</h1>

<p>Confirme seu pré agendamento.</p>
<p>Todos os dados estão corretos?</p>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Telefone</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Horário</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>Necessidade</td>
</tr>


@{
    Consulta infos = new Consulta();
```

if (Model != null)
{
foreach (DadosConsulta consulta in Model)
{

@consulta.Nome
@consulta.Telefone
@consulta.Data
@consulta.Horario
@consulta.Animal
@consulta.Necessidade

}
}
}

```
<a asp-action="Sucesso">Tudo certo!</a>
<a asp-action="PreAgendamento">Corrigir dados</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**//Eh necessario preencher os bojetos antes do foreach**

@model List
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Pré agendamento";
}

## Confirme suas informações

Confirme seu pré agendamento.

Todos os dados estão corretos?

Nome
    Telefone
    Data
    Horário
    Animal
    Necessidade

@{
Consulta infos = new Consulta();

```
    infos.Nome = "Jose";
    infos.Telefone = "(011) 9-8623-6091";
    infos.Data = "10/10/2020";
    infos.Horario = "14:30";
    infos.Animal = "Macaco";
    infos.Necessidade = "Preencher objetos";


foreach (DadosConsulta consulta in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@consulta.Nome</td>
        <td>@consulta.Telefone</td>
        <td>@consulta.Data</td>
        <td>@consulta.Horario</td>
        <td>@consulta.Animal</td>
        <td>@consulta.Necessidade</td>
    </tr>
}
```

}

Tudo certo!
Corrigir dados

Comment: Vc tem que preecher os valores dos objesto antes de entrar no foreach. O certo e preenhcer os valores no backend buscando no banco de dados

Comment: Ainda não parti pro banco de dados :( Mas vou ajeitar o código novamente, muito obrigada pelas dicas